# Purpose of t before $ in HTML Python template

Tags: python, web.py

What is the purpose of inserting `t` before `$` symbol when making HTML templates in python web.py framework:

```
$def with (todos)
<ul>
$for todo in todos:
    <li id="t$todo.id">$todo.title</li> <!-- at this line of code -->
</ul>
```

From web.py [documentation](https://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial) of making simple todo web app when selecting todos from database table by item `id` i didn't find any reference for the purpose of putting `t` before `$` in `t$todo.id`.

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: That's a variable reference (to a variable named `$todo`).

Comment: Without knowing this framework specifically, but being familiar with other templating libraries, I'd suspect it's just a literal `t`, so when `$todo.id` is replaced by the engine with, say, `5`, the output becomes `<li id="t5">...`.

Comment: @fsimonjetz So t is just a reference name for the id tag in the html template

Answer (score 1):

I think this is too long for a comment, so I post it as answer.

The important thing to understand here is that rendering engines go through the template and look for *special elements* that are then replaced or processed in some other way. In this case, special elements are obviously marked by a dollar sign. Everything else is just carried over to the output *literally*, such as the html tags and the `t` before the variable `$todo.id`.

So, if the template contains the pattern `<li id="t$todo.id">`, the renderer will recognize `$todo.id` and replace it with the corresponding value, e.g., `5`. The rest is just copied, so you get `<li id="t5">`. I guess it's just to make the ids more meaningful for easier access via CSS or JavaScript. You could omit the `t` as well or replace it with something else:

```html
<li id="$todo.id"> => <li id="5">
<li id="todo$todo.id"> => <li id="todo5">
<li id="really-important$todo.id"> => <li id="really-important5">
```

Comment: Dollar sign $ actually refer to python variable in the html templates according to web.py documentation.

However your answer make sense and very clear to the point, thank you.